# PHP , Sum Of Common Division 2 Numbers

Tags: php, sum, greatest-common-divisor

I want to Sum of Common Division Between two number,
in below is my code , and output is maghsom moshtarak is=24612
but Goal is 12 only; 
please help me,

```
<?php
$m=0;
$j=6;
$h=12;

function SumCommon($j,$h)
{
 echo"maghsom moshtarak is=";  
    for($i=1;$i<=$h;$i++)
    {
        if(($j%$i==0)&&($h%$i==0))
        {

            Sum($i);

        }
    }
}

function Sum($i)
{
    $i+=$i;
    $m=$i;
    echo $m;  
}


SumCommon($j,$h);
?>
```

Comment: Without actually having tested this, the last two digits in your output are "12" which is the same as your answer. Is your issue being caused by Sum() echoing the results of the calculation? - is Sum() echoing 2, 4, 6, 12? Perhaps put all of the results in an array and select the one you actually need?

Comment: @Doug you are right... Good observation

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$m=0;
$j=6;
$h=12;

function SumCommon($j,$h)
{
 echo "maghsom moshtarak is=";  
    for($i=1;$i<=$h;$i++)
    {
        if(($i%$j==0)&&($i%$h==0)) /* this is changed */
        {

            Sum($i);

        }
    }
}

function Sum($i)
{
    /* no need to use $i+=$i */
    $m=$i;
    echo $m;  
}

SumCommon($j,$h);
?>
```

** Refined Code **

```
<?php
$j=6;
$h=12;

function SumCommon($j,$h)
{
 echo "maghsom moshtarak is=";  
    for($i=1;$i<=$h;$i++)
    {
        if(($i%$j==0)&&($i%$h==0)) /* this is changed */
        {

            echo $i;

        }
    }
}

SumCommon($j,$h);
?>
```

Comment: What's the point of even having a function that reassigns a variable? It's just using more memory.